# TYPO3 - How to remove CType gridelement in TCEFORM

Tags: typo3, tx-gridelements

I know that I remove items for individual pages with

```
TCEFORM.tt_content.CType.removeItems = header,text, ...
```

How can I remove `gridelement`? I tried `gridelemet`, `gridelements`, `grid_element`, `grid_elements`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct CType for Gridelements would be gridelements_pi1.
Another way would be to use a feature of Gridelements instead and put gridelements_pi1 to the set of disallowed CTypes. Works within both page and CE backend layouts.

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/gridelements/Chapters/GridTsSyntax/Index.html

If you want to fully remove grid setups via TSconfig instead, you have to remove their configurations and not just the CType.

```
tx_gridelements.setup >
```

would remove entries completely.

```
tx_gridelements.setup.identifier >
```

would remove a specific configuration for the gridelement "identifier"

Of course this is only possible for gridelements that are configured by TSconfig and not by database records.

Comment: Thanks, but TCEFORM.tt_content.CType.removeItems = gridelements_pi1 does not work. Gridelements are still selectable.

Comment: Tested here with latest CMS 8 and it properly removes the entry from the CType drop down when editing a content element. But I guess it's not what you actually want to just remove the entry there, is it?